# Не могу запушить по ssh

Tags: git, ssh, wsl

По SSH склонировал, а запушить не могу.
На ПК1 PyCharm открыт проект в WSL. там делаю

```
git push
```

Все хорошо пушится.
Перехожу в соседнюю папку - делаю тоже самое и выпадает ошибка

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

На ПК2 тот же репозиторий с тем же SSH-ключом прекрасно пушит.. Уже всю голову сломал..

Команда на ПК1

```
sudo ssh -T git@github.com
```

Тоже выдает ошибку

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

--
UPD

SSH-ключ везде один и тот же (что на ПК1 что на ПК2 что на GitHub). Обе папки на ПК1  - это проекты с GitHub.

UPD2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD3 (без sudo)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем тут `sudo`????

Comment: https://docs.github.com/ru/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: @Alexey Ten, я всяко пробовал - это просто один из вариантов

Comment: @Эникейщик, я там уже был и уже от бессилия пришел сюда)

Comment: магии нет. Вывод `git remote -v` и `ssh-add -l` в студию

Comment: Прекратите писать `sudo` без необходимости. При нормальной работает он не нужен и только всё путает (в частности потому что зачищает переменные окружения)

Comment: Имя пользователя в `origin git@github.com:USERNAME/....` и в `Hi USERNAME! ...` совпадают?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, за комментарии, во-общем, решение было простое. Надо было просто отвлечься на полчасика и с чистой головой зайти (а то глаз замыливается и думаешь, что это уже делал).

Во-общем, я решил еще раз пройтись с самого начала и пошел с проверки прав на файлы. [И это помогло!](https://chmod%20700%20%7E/.ssh%20chmod%20644%20%7E/.ssh/authorized_keys%20chmod%20644%20%7E/.ssh/known_hosts%20chmod%20644%20%7E/.ssh/config%20chmod%20600%20%7E/.ssh/id_rsa%20chmod%20644%20%7E/.ssh/id_rsa.pub%20chmod%20600%20%7E/.ssh/github_rsa%20chmod%20644%20%7E/.ssh/github_rsa.pub%20chmod%20600%20%7E/.ssh/mozilla_rsa%20chmod%20644%20%7E/.ssh/mozilla_rsa.pub) (Хотя я уже думал, что проверял права, но видимо - плохо проверял)

Продублирую сюда решение на случай если ссылка пропадет:

**Права доступа к файлам для ssh ключей и конфигурации.**

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/github_rsa
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/github_rsa.pub
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/mozilla_rsa
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/mozilla_rsa.pub
```